# How to extract the html code from webview to textview?

Tags: java, android, html, webview, jsoup

Its been a week since I start searching this question on the internet, But I cant get the solution.

I want to get the html code from webview and put it in a textview on android.
I cant use jsoup connect because...
I cant explain it too much, this is my example(example only)

On webview I have https://facebook.com(already login my fb account)

I cant use jsoup connect https://facebook.com because the html is On the fb login activity, I mean not login from facebook

I hope you understand

Comment: Using **JSoup** to log into **FaceBook** isn't possible because **FaceBook** has put effort into their "Login Security" to prevent people from using scrapers to download all their posts and their photos. You could use (possibly) **Selenium**, although the first page of the [Selenium Documentation](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/worst_practices/) explicitly explains that using Selenium to scrape people's Facebook Posts is a worst practice - right here: [Gmail, email and Facebook logins](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/worst_practices/gmail_email_and_facebook_logins/)

Answer (score 0):

Create a load listener

```
class HTMLListener{
    public void processHTML(String html)
    {
        Log.e("output_html",html);
        // Then you can set your textview with html
    }
}
```

then in your webview config add this

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new HTMLListener(), "LOADHTML");
```

then in webview client;

```
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
 
                return true;
        }              
       
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url,
                        Bitmap favicon) {
        }
       
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl("javascript:window.LOADHTML.processHTML('<html>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</html>');");
        }
});
```